# ¿Cómo terminar de configurar android estudio?

Tags: android-studio

Hago esta pregunta porque cuando creo un proyecto nuevo en android estudio nunca logro compilarlo por primera vez pues cuando está compilando me muestra el siguiente error:

> Gradle sync failed: No cached version of
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10 available for offline mode.
>            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Por favor, si pudieran decirme por qué este error y cómo lo soluciono. Lo agradecería mucho, es importante destacar que se desea trabajar con android studio manera offline y se está ejecutando sobre window 7. Además ya tiene configurado el SDK y el JDK

Comment: he hecho lo que me habeis indicado y creo que hay avances ahora me da la siguiente exepcion Gradle sync failed: Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Answer (score 2):

Revisa que no tengas activada la opción "Offline work" de Gradle, esta es la secuencia para acceder desde el menú :

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > Build tools > `Gradle`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sincroniza tu proyecto con los archivos Gradle!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline) en inglés.

En Mac **OSx** es similar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

1.-

File->Settings->Gradle->Global Gradle Settings (Versiones 0.6.0 o anteriores)

Y desmarca Offline work

En OSX

Preferences->Gradle->Global Gradle Setting

En versiones recientes

File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build tools->Gradle

2.- Reinicia Android Studio y Vuelve a Abrir el Proyecto para iniciar una nueva sincronizacion

3.- Una vez hecho esto vuelve a marcar la opcion Offline Work