# Problema al intentar crear un nuevo proyecto en AndroidStudio 2.0

Tags: android-studio, android

Estoy intentando crear un nuevo proyecto en AndroidStudio 2.0. Instalé el SDK y configuré la ruta de dicho SDK para AndroidStudio, pero cuando estoy finalizando los pasos para crear un nuevo proyecto, que marco la casilla "Phone and Tablet" y le doy Siguiente, se me queda en una pantalla que dice "Installing Requested Components" y nunca sale de ahí. Al parecer es algún problema con el SDK que tengo instalado pero no logro ver cual es el problema exactamente. A continuación les muestro las capturas de pantalla de los pasos que sigo para esto.
Nota: No dispongo de conección a internet para hacer esto, por lo que no puedo descargar ningún componente desde AndroidStudio directamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen anterior se queda como cargando y no sale de ahí. Luego, cuando abro el SDK Manager me dice que están instalados correctamente todos los paquetes del SDK como muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sugiero que utilices el android studio en Linux, no presenta ningun problema y en cuestiones de la emulacion de las AVD es supremamente rapido que en windows...

Comment: Si no me equivoco es **necesario** estar conectado a internet para este paso... Piensa que lo que está haciendo (en principio) es descargar las depencdencias y sin conexióna internet por eso te aparece en blanco. Después de descargar las dependencias sí que podrías trabajar sin conexión.

Answer (score 5):

Adriana, puedes ver como instalado son los sdk, pero al crear un nuevo proyecto se necesitan descargar las dependencias definidas en el `build.gradle`.

Conecta a internet al menos en una ocasión para descargar las dependencias y posteriormente puedes activar la opción "Offline Work" para no necesitar descargar desde internet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13451/95